# Compactness of, and the existence of certain subspaces of, the Helly space

Tags: general-topology

Taking $I = [0,1]$, the [Helly space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly_space) is the subspace of $I^I$ (with the usual Tychonoff product topology) consisting of all *nondecreasing* functions.

I have three questions about this space.

1. Is the Helly space compact?
2. How can I show that the Helly space has a subspace homeomorphic to $D(\mathfrak{c})$, the discrete space of size $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$?
3. How can I show that the Helly space has a subspace homeomorphic to the Sorgenfrey line, $K$?

Comment: $D(c)$ denotes the discrete space with cardinality $c$?

Comment: @tetori  yes. the cardinality of $D(c)$ is $c$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it contains multiple questions which should be asked separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that the Helly space is compact, we will show that the Helly space is a closed subspace of Tychonoff cube $I^\mathfrak{c}$. If $\langle f_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in J}$ is a convergent net over Helly space (that is, every $f_\alpha$ lies on Helly space. Note that the limit of the net does not lie on the Helly space in general.) which converges to $f$. You can check that $f_\alpha(x)\le f_\alpha(y)$ for each $x,y\in I$, $x\le y$ and $\alpha\in J$. Take a limit for $\alpha$ then we get $f(x)\le f(y)$.

We will prove that $D(\mathfrak{c})$ is a subspace of Helly space. Let consider
$$f_c(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }0\le x<c\\ 1/2&\text{if }x=c\\1&\text{if }c<x\le 1\end{cases}$$
and define $D=\{f_c\in I^\mathfrak{c}:c\in I\}$. It is trivial that $D$ is a subspace of Helly space. To prove $D$ is discrete, we will find a open set (in $I^\mathfrak{c}$) $V$ such that $f_a\in V$ and $f_b\notin V$ for all $b\neq a$. However, such open set is easy to constuct: Let
$\pi_a(f)=f(a)$, then $\pi$ is a projection and is continuous. Consider $V=\pi_a^{-1}((1/4,3/4))$

Also, to prove the Sorgenfrey line is a subspace of the Helly space, consider the functions
$$g_c(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }0\le x\le c\\ 1&\text{if }c<x\le 1\end{cases}.$$
Let define $S=\{g_c:0<c<1\}$. We will argue that $S$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ with lower limit topology. Let $\phi:(0,1)\to S$ be a function defined as 
$$\phi(c)=g_c.$$
Obviously, $\phi$ is 1-1 and onto. We will show that $\phi$ sends the open subbasis of $(0,1)$ with lower topology to open set of $S$ and vice versa.
You may know that the topology of $I^\mathfrak{c}$ is generated by $\pi_a^{-1}(O)$, where $O$ is an open interval over $I$ and $a\in I$. You can easily check that

$$\pi_a^{-1}([0,r))\cap S=\{f_c\in S:c\ge a\}$$
$$\pi_a^{-1}((r,1])\cap S=\{f_c\in S:c< a\}$$
$$\pi_a^{-1}((r,s))\cap S=\varnothing\quad\text{for }0<r<s<1$$

so $\phi^{-1}$ sends the open basis of $S$ to the open basis of $(0,1)$ with lower topology. You can easily check the another direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am slow reader,so I will go over your proof and will ask more question about it later when I face any challenge.

Comment: Sorry,but in one point you proved that $D (\mathfrak{c})$ is subspace of Hell space. But what we asked is to show $D (\mathfrak{c})$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of Hell space.I just want to say what you proved is much stronger. do you think the same?

Comment: @Birkary No, I prove that there is a subspace $D$ which is homeomorphic to the discrete space $D(\mathfrak{c})$. $D$ with subspace topology is discrete, but I didn't prove that points in $D$ is isolated. In this proof, $V$ does not contain $f_b$ for all $b\neq a$, but $V$ may contain the elements *not* in $D$.

Comment: The closedness follows easily without nets too: suppose $f$ is not non-decreasing, so there are $p < q$ with $f(p) > f(q)$. Let $r$ be strictly between $f(p)$ and $f(q)$. Then the product open set $O$ that is $(r, 1]$ at coordinate $p$, $[0,r)$ at $q$ all contain functions not in $H$ for the same reason as $f$ is not (and $f$ is in it).